# How to show this function is increasing both intuitively and using formula

Tags: monotone-functions

In a book, it is claimed that the following function is obviously increasing as $x$ gets larger. I tried a few numerical examples for $x$, and it appears to be so. However, it is not clear to me how come it is so obvious. Could anyone point out the reason, please?

$g(x) := \frac{(65-x)*0.8^{65-x}}{1-0.8^{65-x}}; 0 < x < 65.$

My try is as below, let $x_1 < x_2$, it is only necessary to show that $g(x_1) / g(x_2) <1$. Hence,

$
\begin{align}
\frac{g(x_1)}{g(x_2)} = \frac{65-x_1}{65-x_2} * 0.8^{x_2-x_1}*\frac{1-0.8^{65-x_2}}{1-0.8^{65-x_1}}.
\end{align}
$

It is not hard to see the first fraction term is greater than 1; the second term less than 1; and the third item also less than 1. However, it is not clear why the product of these three is less than 1. I guess this relates to the order of increase; i.e. linear increase/decrease  is slower than exponential. However, I could not finish the above formula to reach the desired answer.

Moreover, is there any intuitive explanation why $g(x)$ is obviously increasing, please? Thanks.

**Update:**

I think Rhys' argument can explain when $x$ is small, but not when $x$ gets closer to the upper boundary. The plot of numerator and dominator as well as the function itself is as below. So it is still not clear to me why $g(x)$ is increasing when $x$ is close to 65.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't find it obvious, either.  You have identified the problem in the $65-x$ term.  The graphs [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(65-x)0.8%5E(65-x)%2F(1-0.8%5E(65-x))) shows strongly support the increasing claim.  The claim that exponential dominates over linear is true as the exponent goes to infinity, but we are not doing that here.  For $x$ small the numerator is increasing because each increase of $1$ increases the $0.8^{65-x}$ term by a factor $1.25$ and decreases the $65-x$ term by $1$.  When the $65-x$ term is large that is increasing, but when $x$ goes from $63$ to $64$ the numerator decreases from $1.28$ to $0.8$.  The denominator decreases enough so the expression still increases, but this supports the claim that it is not obvious that the expression is increasing.
[image]

Comment: It's obvious once you realise num is increasing while den is decreasing, but that isn't obvious at a glance.

Comment: @RhysHughes:  but the $65-x$ in the numerator is decreasing, so I don't think it is obvious that the numerator is increasing.  For example, as $x$ goes from $63$ to $64$ the numerator goes from $1.28$ to $0.8$.  It is not increasing over that range.

Answer (score 1):

It's "obvious" (I don't exactly agree as it took a minute to get my head round it) because the numerator of $g(x)$ is increasing; consider that if you have $$(\frac 45)^{30}\cdot  30=(\frac45)^{29}\cdot 24 $$ (when $x=35$), which is obviously smaller than the $(\frac45)^{29}\cdot 29$ (when $x=36$)

and its denominator is decreasing for the same reasons. Because of this, the function is increasing.

Comment: The numerator is increasing because the exponential part grows faster than the linear part. Right?

Comment: Not exactly. The exponential part's growth counteracts the decreasing linear part, as indicated in my middle line.

Comment: The numerator is not increasing as $x$ gets close to $65$.

Comment: Yes, I think Rhys' argument can explain the earlier range, but not when $x$ is close to 65 as I updated.

Comment: @RossMillikan True, however the denominator ostensibly falls at a much greater rate for similar reasons when $x\to 65$.

Comment: It does, but I think that takes it out of the obvious category.

Comment: @RossMillikan Agreed.